# Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:exec en spring boot

Tags: java, netbeans, spring-boot, maven

me sale este error al momento de ejecutar un proyecto en netbeans, mi versión es la 12.3 y estoy utilizando spring boot. he revisado el pom.xml pero no se cual será el error, utilicé la opción de resolución de problemas pero tampoco me ha funcionado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Revisé la versión de maven que tengo y es esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"   
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0   
https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.5</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>
        <groupId>com.sinfloo</groupId>
        <artifactId>CRUDJavaAngular</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>CRUDJavaAngular</name>
        <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
        <properties>
            <java.version>11</java.version>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

Al ampliar los detalles del error con -X, me sale esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Qué comando estás ejecutando?

Comment: @E.Betanzos a que te refieres específicamente?

Comment: Me refiero a cuál comando de Maven es el que termina con ese error.

Comment: @E.Betanzos mvn compile

Comment: Pudieras incluir la salida completa de la consola al ejecutar el comando con la opción `-X`?

Comment: @E.Betanzos puse el pantallazo en la publicación

Comment: No, solo pusiste la parte del error y yo me refiero a TODA la salida de la consola.